# Can elevation data be mapped in R's choropleth (very limited skill)

Tags: r, visualization

I have gone down various rabbit holes for a DataVis project. I attempted to map various states and found the fastest, most reliable way to do this was choropleth, adapted from Census webinar. I did not realize that the API call part of this function had changed and now I'm trying to find another way to include ground elevation without having to insert a new API every time I demo it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.